# Is there an IDA disassembler module for IBM 360/370/390?

Tags: ida, disassembly

Has anyone written an IDA disassembler module for
IBM 360/370/390 or higher processors? Would like
to examine one even though i cannot afford IDA Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This sounds like archeology work :) Nevertheless, such module could be implemented in a week if you know how to use IDA SDK and the instruction set of IBM 360.